# How to load a directive template before evaluating javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas, angularjs-directive, kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS in conjunction with AngularJS and I want to be able to stash the necessary javascript into a directive. All of the [examples](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-rotation-animation-tutorial/) I've seen for KineticJS wrap the required logic in a script tag using the `defer` attribute, i.e.

```
<script defer="defer">
  window.onload = function() { ... }
</script>
```

Is it possible to load the template of the directive while deferring the execution of any business logic (in an equivalent way)? I've tried using the `controller`, `link`, `compile` functions to no avail. Here's an example:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('canvasInitializer', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return {
      template: "<div id='canvas-container'></div>", // load this!
      restrict: 'C',
      compile: function (element, attrs) {
        return {
          post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // defer this?
            $window.onload = function () {
              var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'canvas-container',
                width: 800,
                height: 600
              });

              var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

              var blueRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 50,
                y: 75,
                width: 100,
                height: 50,
                fill: '#00D2FF',
                stroke: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 4
              });

              layer.add(blueRect);
              stage.add(layer);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaaaand suddenly it looks like I found the answer to my problem. Wrapping the logic in `$timeout(function () { ... })` did the trick. Notice that I didn't even provide a specific time for `$timeout`.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .directive('canvasInitializer', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      template: "<div id='canvas-container'></div>"
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function () {
          var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'canvas-container',
            width: 800,
            height: 600
          });

          var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

          var blueRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 50,
            y: 75,
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            fill: '#00D2FF',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4
          });

          layer.add(blueRect);
          stage.add(layer);
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```